# How to combine two std Object in array to single std Object in php

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

I am getting following kind of response

```
  $myObj =   Array
   (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [parameterName] => Age
            [parameterValue] => 14
            [income] => 700000
            [famMember] => 9
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
             [parameterName] => location
             [parameterValue] => Pune
             [income] => 700000
             [famMember] => 9
        )

)
```

What I want is to combine both the stdClass Object as single like

```
   Array
     (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [parameterName] => Age
            [parameterValue] => 14
            [parameterName] => location
            [parameterValue] => Pune
            [income] => 700000
            [famMember] => 9
        )
      )
```

Please Help me How to get it.

Comment: It is not possible to have the two or more indexes equal in the same array.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing so?

Comment: you have to make array for that

Answer (score 0):

You Can use with using `array_merge_recursive()` But your output values are should be an array

For Example:

```
$ar1 = array("color" =>  "red", "name"=> 5);
$ar2 = array("name"=>10, "color" => "green");
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($result);
```

Output is:

```
    Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => red
            [1] => green
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 10
        )

)
```